# Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location'

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, google-cloud-platform, intellij-idea

I am trying to connect my springboot and hibernate project to my gcp mysql database. However when i try to connect tot he data base I get an The Application Default Credentials are not available error. I am trying to set the credentials location in my application.properties file however even with what i beleive is the correct dependecies I am getting Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location'

here is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.seniorproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>Backend</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Backend</name>
    <description>backend for senior project</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

here is my application.properties file

```
#datasource configurations
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql:///seniorproject-db?cloudSqlInstance=seniorproject-376014:us-central1:seniorproject-db&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory
#spring.datasource.username=root
#spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=seniorproject-376014
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=classpath:/src/main/resources/seniorprojectKey.json

spring.cloud.gcp.sql.enabled=true
```

here is the main file im trying to run

```
package com.seniorproject.Backend;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BackendApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BackendApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

I have tried changing around what dependecies I use but none seem to let me use the spring.cloud.gcp configuration property.
Im pretty new to spring boot and hibernate so any help in appreciated.